# Spring-cloud-gateway: HTTP400 when more than 30 headers in request

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

I'm using spring-cloud-gateway as an API gateway which sits behind an apache layer responsible for pre-authentication (single sign on). This layer adds a bunch of headers to the incoming requests to my spring-cloud-gateway app and when this number exceeds 30 headers. I get back a HTTP 400 response from the gateway.

I have a custom filter in place that talks to a back-end user service in order to do enforce authorization. This filter adds more headers to the exchange's request.

```java
HttpHeaders headers = new HttpHeaders();
headers.setContentType(APPLICATION_JSON);
headers.set(PRINCIPAL, userId);
HttpEntity<Void> responseType = new HttpEntity<Void>(headers);
ResponseEntity<UserDto> response = restTemplate.exchange(CURRENT_USER_ENDPOINT, HttpMethod.GET, responseType, UserDto.class);
addUserDetailsToHeaders(exchange, response.getBody());
```

For some reason this filter is causing interference for any gateway requests with > 30 headers
The response body I get from the gateway when >30 headers is shown below.

```
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Bad Request</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <h1><p>Bad Request</p></h1>
    Error parsing headers: &#x27;limit request headers fields&#x27;
  </body>
</html>
```

I can simulate the issue when running my gateway locally by using curl. For example:

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/my-api-app/' -H 'Connection: keep-alive' -H 'Cache-Control: max-age=0' -H 'Upgrade-Insecure-Requests: 1' -H 'User-Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/76.0.3809.100 Safari/537.36' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Mode: navigate' -H 'Sec-Fetch-User: ?1' -H 'Accept: text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3' -H 'Sec-Fetch-Site: none' -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' -H 'Accept-Language: en-GB,en;q=0.9,en-US;q=0.8,ja;q=0.7' -H 'Cookie: 567583457' -H 'uid: 1234567' -H 'employee: N' -H 'x-forwarded-proto: https' -H 'x-forwarded-for: 10.45.67.65, 172.16.8.1' -H 'X-Forwarded-Host: xxxxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'X-Forwarded-Server: xxxxxxxxxxxxx' -H 'Ct_request_id: 11' -H 'managername: xxxxxxxx, xxxxx'  -H 'Ctscuserkeywords: NotExpired,PasswordPolicy' -H 'Destinationindicator: IE' -H 'a: b' -H 'c: d' -H 'derek: test'  --compressed
```

I can aslo simulate the same 400 response using the spring-cloud-gateway-sample project by hitting it with this curl (so the real limit looks like 90)

```
curl 'http://localhost:8080/get' -H 'key1: val' -H 'key2: val' -H 'key3: val' -H 'key4: val' -H 'key5: val' -H 'key6: val' -H 'key7: val' -H 'key8: val' -H 'key9: val' -H 'key10: val' -H 'key11: val' -H 'key12: val' -H 'key13: val' -H 'key14: val' -H 'key15: val' -H 'key16: val' -H 'key17: val' -H 'key18: val' -H 'key19: val' -H 'key20: val' -H 'key21: val' -H 'key22: val' -H 'key23: val' -H 'key24: val' -H 'key25: val' -H 'key26: val' -H 'key27: val' -H 'key28: val' -H 'key29: val' -H 'key30: val' -H 'key31: val' -H 'key32: val' -H 'key33: val' -H 'key34: val' -H 'key35: val' -H 'key36: val' -H 'key37: val' -H 'key38: val' -H 'key39: val' -H 'key40: val' -H 'key41: val' -H 'key42: val' -H 'key43: val' -H 'key44: val' -H 'key45: val' -H 'key46: val' -H 'key47: val' -H 'key48: val' -H 'key49: val' -H 'key50: val' -H 'key51: val' -H 'key52: val' -H 'key53: val' -H 'key54: val' -H 'key55: val' -H 'key56: val' -H 'key57: val' -H 'key58: val' -H 'key59: val' -H 'key60: val' -H 'key61: val' -H 'key62: val' -H 'key63: val' -H 'key64: val' -H 'key65: val' -H 'key66: val' -H 'key67: val' -H 'key68: val' -H 'key69: val' -H 'key70: val' -H 'key71: val' -H 'key72: val' -H 'key73: val' -H 'key74: val' -H 'key75: val' -H 'key76: val' -H 'key77: val' -H 'key78: val' -H 'key79: val' -H 'key80: val' -H 'key81: val' -H 'key82: val' -H 'key83: val' -H 'key84: val' -H 'key85: val' -H 'key86: val' -H 'key87: val' -H 'key88: val' -H 'key89: val' -H 'key90: val' -H 'key91: val'
```

Comment: I plug that curl command in and it works fine for me. What version are you using? Are you sure that error is coming from gateway and not the downstream app?

Comment: Spencer, yes I'm 100% sure its coming from the gateway. I even wrote a special downstream python app to log all requests, it never gets hit. I do have some custom filters though. Also wired up a Eureka discovery client. I'm using Greenwich.SR2. Interesting thing is that the request does go through my 3 filters

Comment: I can't reproduce it. Can you provide a sample project?

Comment: Spencer, thanks. Turns out it was one of my custom filters. My custom filter was talking to another service to get user details (authorization) and for some reason this was interfering with the request passing through the filter chain. In my custom filter I is using Spring's restTemplate.exchange(....).  I think its better if I update the question with more details now... Hard to fit all details in here

Comment: I updated the question. I was able to reproduce it by hitting the spring-cloud-sample app with > 90 headers. I know its unrealistic but I have limited control over the layer sitting in front of our PCF instance which is adding loads of headers.

Comment: When I submit your curl request to httpbin.org thru the gateway I get that html, what you didn't show is the headers that come back, which includes `Server: nginx`. So the gateway is not returning that error.

Comment: Thanks Spencer. Yes thats true, httpbin must be on nginx and its giving back that header which is useful. It put me on the right track. In my case I found that the problem was not with the gateway (as you correctly say) but in fact the requests were being rejected by cloudfoundry's cf router. Thats why I didn't see any traffic to my app. Unfortunately cf router does not add a 'Server' header to the response.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem turned out to be cloudfoundry's cf router rejecting the request. No problem with the gateway. What made it confusing was that cf router does not add any response header when it returns a 400.

I had a custom filter adding one particular header containing a comma separated list which was quite long (200 to 300chars). I reduced the length of this and then it worked.

Comment: how did you find out that it was cloudfoundry's cf router?

Answer (score 0):

Are you using embedded Tomcat?

Check out this article on the issue: https://thewebspark.com/2017/12/06/tomcat-request-header-too-large-resolved/

> To resolve this error, either check if the request made is GET or POST?
>
> If it is GET request then change it to HTTP POST the error will get resolved in most of the cases as  the URL length goes beyond 2000 characters. In this case, it’s better to use POST or split the URL.
>
> maxHttpHeaderSize: The maximum size of the request and response HTTP header, specified in bytes. If not specified, this attribute is set to 4096 (4 KB).
>
> You will find it in
>
> $TOMCAT_HOME/conf/server.xml
>
> In server.xml change the HTTP/1.1 Connector entry and set the maxHttpHeaderSize to “65536” (64Kb in bytes) as shown below:
>
> Connector port="8080" maxHttpHeaderSize="65536" protocol="HTTP/1.1" ...

If using embedded Tomcat, try configuring it to increase the max header size:
https://www.baeldung.com/spring-boot-configure-tomcat

If not using Embedded Tomcat, I also found this on the same subject from Pivotal: https://community.pivotal.io/s/article/spring-boot-app-rejects-http-request-with-total-header-size-larger-than-8kb

Comment: Nope, gateway requires netty

Comment: Checking into Netty then, it also appears to be a configuration setting: https://github.com/reactor/reactor-netty/blob/0.7.x/src/main/java/reactor/ipc/netty/http/server/HttpServerOptions.java#L99  Looks like Netty default is 8k